# Cannot unzip and install the Spark 'tar' file. Getting error 'No such file or directory' (Ubuntu for Windows)

Tags: ubuntu

I just downloaded the Spark 'tar' file and trying to unzip and install it on Ubuntu for windows. I'm  getting the following error:

```
sislam@domain:/home$ sudo tar -zxvf spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
tar (child): spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I've been trying every possible site I can research but cannot figure out the solution. I'm kind of new to linux world and any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Syed

[image]

Comment: I tried to check if the file exist by using 'pwd' and 'ls' commands as well but not showing all the files as expected.

Comment: Normally. `/home` would contain only top-level user directories - you actual files would be in `/home/sislam` or somesuch.

Comment: You need to find the directory where you saved that file, then use `cd` to switch to that directory, then run that command.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Actually it was in home\sislam directory and it wasn't working. So, I just tried to run it from the root dir. I made sure my current dir with 'pwd' and ran the unzip command. When I do 'ls', it's not showing any file even though from the Windows Explorer, I can see the tar file. Any other suggestions pls? Really appreciate the help as it's been 2 days I couldn't figure out this simple issue! about to give up on learning spark..:)

Answer (score 3):

Your tgz is present in your Windows home directory which is different from your Ubuntu WSL home directory and should be mounted as `/mnt/c/Users/sislam`. To extract it in your Linux home, adjust the path to the file:

```
# cd to /home/sislam if you're not already there
cd ~
tar -zxvf /mnt/c/Users/sislam/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue with the help of Linux professional. I was downloading the file in wrong directory. It was as simple as that. Ubuntu for Windows pointing to a specific user directory within the AppData folder and so on. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Syed